# code change from php to coldfusion

Tags: php, coldfusion

Having the following code in php

```
print $row['from_id'].';;;'.$row2['username'];
```

i changed to to coldfusion as;

```
<cfoutput>#res.from_id# ;;; #res2.username#</cfoutput>
```

but it is giving me a error:

Error:

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [title="2 "]
```

because the file is called in jquery

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'load.cfm',                            
                data: 'own_id='+own_id,
                success: function(o){                                               
                    if(o != 0){
                        var substr = o.split(';;;');        
                        if($('div[title="'+substr[0]+'"]').length == 0){                    
                            iopen(substr[0],substr[1],1);
                        }                                               

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the spacing in:

```
<cfoutput>#res.from_id# ;;; #res2.username#</cfoutput>
                       ^---^
```

This is making the `substr[0]` have a space in it. You need to trim the whitespace, or simply remove it, seeing as there is no spacing in the PHP.

```
 <cfoutput>#res.from_id#;;;#res2.username#</cfoutput>
```